# Cardinalities in which abelian group theory is categorical?

Tags: model-theory, abelian-groups

I want to find all cardinalities in which abelian group theory is categorical. It is clear for some finite cardinalities (how to determine them?) by fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, but what about infinite ones?

Comment: $C_2\times C_2$ and $C_4$ are each abelian groups of order $4$, but they're not isomorphic.

Comment: @JohnColeman Seems that I didn't understood fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups correctly, thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you!

Comment: @JohnColeman Actually, $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ **is** isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Of course, I dashed that off without thinking. +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 3):

For any infinite set $X$, the groups $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus{X}}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus{X}}$ are two non-isomorphic abelian groups having the same cardinality as $X$.

For a finite cardinality $n$, all abelian groups of order $n$ are isomorphic if and only if $n$ is square-free.